# Svg served as document behind nginx

Tags: nginx, svg

When I open up my .svg image in the browser (on a webpage serving static content with nginx), I see the XML, not the image.
I have added image/svg+xml svg svgz; to /etc/nginx/mime.types, however there is no content type set on the svg.

I have no idea what else could be the issue.

Comment: What does your `server` block look like?

Comment: @RichardSmith I forgot to include the mime.types file, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake, without this it will not work:

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```